# Showing data from jointed tables in a Laravel View

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a problem for a school project, the project is a website where you can get informations about vidéo games (name, cover of the game and release date) and simply add games to your list if you want to play them later or even if you want to add the games you already finished, this is a simple library app. In order to get the game added to your list, you need to go on the page where the games are and add it with a simple button to your list.

Now that i resumed the app function, let me explain how the site works.

The site is build with laravel 6, all functions that i wanted to implemant are working except one, adding a game to your list. Adding a game to your list is fine Database side but my problem is that i can't display the list of games added to my "profil" page.

This is my user table named utilisateurs https://ibb.co/pLFgDVt .

Here is the list table named listes https://ibb.co/16vhzDb .

I made a join in both tables with the utilisateur_id that reffers to the id of the user in utilisateurs table. (when you are logged in and click on the add button it gets the user id of the logged in user and save it in the table "listes").

Everything is working but I dont succeed in displaying the games that a user add to his list in my view.

Here is my code :

-my CompteController.php for the profil page (showing profil img, name and logout button).

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class CompteController extends Controller
{
    public function accueil() {

        if(auth()->guest()) {
            return redirect('/connexion')->withErrors([
                'email' => "Vous devez être connecté pour voir cette page."
            ]);
        }
        $titre = "Profil";
        return \view('profile', ['titre' => $titre]);
    }

    public function deconnexion () {

        auth()->logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }

    public function update_avatar(Request $request){

        $request->validate([
            'avatar' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:10240',
        ]);

        $utilisateur = Auth::user();

        $avatarName = $utilisateur->id.'_avatar'.time().'.'.request()->avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $request->avatar->storeAs('avatars',$avatarName);

        $utilisateur->avatar = $avatarName;
        $utilisateur->save();

        return back()
            ->with('success','You have successfully upload image.');

    }
}
```

-ListeController.php (the function "ajout" get the game name and the id of the user logged in when you click on this button and add it on the "listes" table https://ibb.co/XDPPkCP ).

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Liste;

class ListeController extends Controller
{
    public function ajout(){

        $liste = new Liste();

        $liste->nom = request('nom');
        $liste->utilisateur_id = Auth::id();
        $liste->save();

        return redirect('/prochainement');

    }

    

    
}
```

As i already said, adding the datas in the database is working.

Here is my migrations files so you can see how i set the database :

-Migration Utilisateurs table :

```
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUtilisateursTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
    Schema::create('utilisateurs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->varchar('pseudo');
        $table->varchar('avatar');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('mot_de_passe');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('utilisateurs');
}
```

}

-Migration Listes table :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateListeTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('listes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->text('nom');
            $table->integer('utilisateur_id');
            $table->boolean('statut');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('liste');
    }
}
```

Here is the view for the Profil page :

```
@extends('layout')
@section('container')
<section id="profile">
    <div class="bloc">
        <h2>Mon Profil</h2>
        <img src="img/soulignement.png" alt="" class="soulignement">
        <div>
            <h3>{{ Auth::user()->pseudo }}</h3>
            <img src="storage/avatars/{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}" class="imageProfil"> <br>
            <div id="centrageBouton">
            <div class="tooltip"> <button class="boutons btnBasique" id="image-profil"><span><i
                            class="fas fa-upload"></i></span></button> <span class="tooltiptext">Changer d'image de profil</span>
            </div> 
        </div><br>
            <div class="formulaire-image">
                <form action="/mon-compte" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formulaireUpload">
                    @csrf

                    <input type="file" size="60" class="boutonUpload " name="avatar" id="avatarFile" >

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="boutonEnvoie">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div><br>
            <div class="bloc-aligner">

                <button class="boutons btnBasique"><span>Changer mon MDP</span></button>
               <button class="boutons btnBasique"> <a href="/deconnexion"><span> Déconnexion</span></a></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mesJeux">
            <h3>Mes Jeux</h3>
            <img src="img/soulignement.png" alt="" class="soulignement">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nom</td>
                    <td>Statut</td>
                    <td>Actions</td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild</td>
                    <td>finis</td>
                    <td><button class="boutons btnBasique"><span>finis</span></button> <br><button
                            class="boutons btnBasique"><span>à finir</span></button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<script src="js/Main.js"></script>
<script src="js/AffichageBoutonForm.js"></script>
@endsection
```

Now my question is, how can i display the game name added in database in "listes" table that a user added to his list when he is logged in and on his profil page.

I'm sorry if i am not clear, english is not my native langage and i am kind of tired because i searched almost all day about this.

If you guys need complementary informations just tell me and i'll give them to you.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to get a list of the user's games and pass that list to the view. `Auth::user()->listes` should work if you have relationships set up in the `Utilisateur` model.

Comment: I dont have relationships set up in my model, are you sure it will work when someone will login and will try to watch his list?